# Ok to repeat same measurement in different column and different row of design matrix for multilevel model?

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, lavaan

I have a process that unfolds in time for each participant like this:

```
measurement1 -> event1 -> measurement2 -> event2 -> measurement3
```

Each of these are continuous variables (measurements and events). My hypothesis is that the events impact the immediately subsequent measurement, controlling for the prior measurement. I would like to estimate that effect.

I could fit a structural equation model with two regressions:

```
measurement2 ~ event1 + measurement1

measurement3 ~ event2 + measurement2
```

And fix the two slopes of event1 and event2 to be equal. However, I am missing many datapoints for measurement3 and so I lose a very large chunk of the sample from listwise deletion.

Can I reshape the design matrix so I have columns for [measurement_pre, measurement_post, event, participant_id] and then fit a model that looks like:

```
measurement_post ~ event_pre + measurement_pre + 
participant_id_random_effects
```

In other words, measurement2 would be duplicated as being measurement_pre and measurement_post in different rows.

Is this okay to do? Will it mess up anything such as standard errors or anything? Is there a better solution?

EDIT:
Posting `lavaan` code with structural equation model method

```
m <- '

phq_1_sc ~ phq_0_sc + emo_delta*delta_avg1_sc
phq_2_sc ~ phq_1_sc + emo_delta*delta_avg2_sc

'
fit <- sem(m, 
            missing="fiml",
            dat)
summary(fit)
```

Comment: Why not use full-information maximum likelihood estimation in your SEM program to recover the missing data? This estimation procedure should be available in R (e.g., `lavaan`) and Stata (`sem`) as well as the specialized SEM programs (e.g., AMOS, Mplus, LISREL, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your response Erik. It still says it using only 646 out of the 1666 observations when I use FIML in lavaan. Is it because the missing observations are in the dependent variables rather than merely independent variables?

Comment: Can you post your `lavaan` code?

Comment: I have done so now